# High frequency data refresh with Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cron

I'm developing a service using GAE for android clients and need to refresh application data on a regular basis, say once a minute.

In terms of architecture, this is how the application works:

- User launches app and retrieves market data from service running on GAE
- The GAE service itself calls an external web service to retrieve market data, filters results and sends for user display
- The market prices should get updated once a minute

I know GAE offers cron jobs for automated scheduled tasks, but from what I understood it's not suitable for such high frequency tasks (or not even supported)

What's the best practice/tools I can use for this use case?

Also, is it recommended to update data in the background regardless of application being open? Or just update as soon as the user launches?

[EDIT] I would also like to know if pulling data every minute is the right approach, or should the service push instead?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If data pulled by service is not specific to any user, running a cron job to load every min should be ok. Each user request get the data from this cached data. You can still control when your cron can run . Does it need to run only day time.

Comment: So if I want my users' data to be updated every minute from the cache, would it happen silently in the background even if app is inactive? Or update only when   app is launched?

Answer (score 3):

`"it's not suitable for such high frequency tasks (or not even supported)"` - this is not exactly correct.

Cron jobs can run at intervals as low as 1 minute, see [The schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_The_schedule_format):

> The following are examples of schedules:
>
> ```
> every 12 hours
> every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00
> every day 00:00
> every monday 09:00
> 2nd,third mon,wed,thu of march 17:00
> 1st monday of sep,oct,nov 17:00
> 1 of jan,april,july,oct 00:00
> ```
>
> If you don't need to run a recurring job at a specific time, but
>   instead only need to run it at regular intervals, use the form:
>
> ```
> every N (hours|mins|minutes) ["from" (time) "to" (time)]
> ```

So for 1 min interval you can use:

```
every 1 minutes
```

If you need lower than 1 minute intervals you can use [the deferred library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred?hl=en) - tasks can be delayed from the enqueueing moment with time values specified in seconds:

> deferred.defer(do_something_expensive, "Foobie bletch", 12,
>   **_countdown=30**, _queue="myqueue")

The answer to the last questions really depends on how you want your app to behave: have the data immediately available for the client app when the client app starts or have the client app wait until the backend collects the data.

If you're just relaying the collected data to the client either way is fine, there is no "common practice" (other than driven by higher costs for constant updates, of course). But if you plan to also offer results from processing historic data you'll probably have to go with constant updates (or maybe just during the market open hours).

**Update:**

The [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) are preferable to the deferred library, the deferred functionality is available using the optional `countdown` or `eta` arguments to [taskqueue.add()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.taskqueue):

> - countdown -- Time in seconds into the future that this task should run or be leased. Defaults to zero. Do not specify this argument if
>     you specified an eta.
> - eta -- A `datetime.datetime` that specifies the absolute earliest time at which the task should run. You cannot specify this argument if
>     the countdown argument is specified. This argument can be time
>     zone-aware or time zone-naive, or set to a time in the past. If the
>     argument is set to None, the default value is now. For pull tasks, no
>     worker can lease the task before the time indicated by the eta
>     argument.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. In general, is constantly updating data in the background common practice? Or just update when user launches the app?

Comment: It depends on how many users you have. If you always have someone using an app, there is no point in checking individual sessions. If you have very few users, then there is no point in running updates for 24 hours.

Comment: Not sure I understood what you meant by "no point in checking individual sessions". Are you suggesting I push updates every minute to users instead of clients pulling data every minute?