# How to schedule repeated jobs or tasks from user parameters in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine and I want like to be able to schedule jobs based users' parameters.

I know this can be done with cron jobs, but looks like it does not allow any flexibility from the user's point of view, but it allows only to schedule predefined jobs.

For example, suppose I have a news app where users can subscribe to different topics: I want the admin to be able to decide when to send a summary email, for instance, every day at 8am, and I want him to be able to edit this.

Is there anything that provides this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to star [Issue 3638: Cron jobs to be scheduled programatically](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3638)

Meanwhile you can write your own implementation: have a generic cron job running periodically (every 1 minute being the finest resolution) and inside that cron job check user-programmed scheduling data persisted somewhere (in the datastore for example) and, if needed, trigger execution of whatever is needed to be executed, either inlined or by enqueueing a task in some task queue.

It's possible to drive the scheduling resolution even under 1 minute, if needed, see [High frequency data refresh with Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206365/high-frequency-data-refresh-with-google-app-engine/35206885#35206885)

Answer (score 3):

For my debts tracking app [DebtsTracker.io](https://debtstracker.io/) I've implemented it manually.

When a user creates a debt record he can specify due date that is stored in an unindexed `DueDate` and indexed `ReminderDateTime` fields.

I have a cron that query records with `ReminderDateTime < today` and sends notifications. Once notification sent the `ReminderDateTime` is set to null or far future so it's not picked in next cron run. If user hits `Remind me again` I am updating the `ReminderDateTime` to some date in future (user decides when).

If `ReminderDateTime` is closer then cron interval then I simply create I put a task to queue with appropriate delay.

This works very well and is very cheap to run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How often do you run your cron? I guess there is a flaw in this approach which is the need of having an high frequency cron job that looks up the db looking for jobs to run.

Comment: Actually I run job just once a day. If there is tasks for the coming day I put tasks to queue. So actually I'm querying `ReminderDateTime < tomorrow`.

Comment: Mmmm, maybe your problem is different? Maybe you run your job just once. For instance, you put a debt record and a reminder at some datetime, and you want to be remined at that time and date. My problem instead, is to launch a job repeatedly at a specified time and intervals (for example send email every mon, wed, fri at 9pm). But I also want the user to be able to edit this, if he decides that since now on he wants to send emails every day(mon to sun, at 3pm)

Comment: @MarcoGalassi, no, it's same kind of problem. I have similar for recurrent debts (like bills). You simply on executing task update `ReminderDateTime` with the next value. Very straight forward.

Comment: There is something I must be missing, i'm probably just stupid. What happens if you run your cron to read all the jobs at 9pm, and the user, at 3pm decides that he wants to schedule something at 4pm? Also, how do you manage multiple jobs in a day, like I want to run this job 3 times a day, at 9am, at 1pm and at 4pm?

Comment: In you case a UserJob class would have a CalcNextDate() method that returns next run date based on user input. You store it to the indexed field.

If it's less then next cron run (let's say need to be run in 5 hours and cron will be run in 23 hours) you put it to task queue with delay for 5 hours. Once task is executed either by triggered from queue or by picking by cron you update the NextRun field and again either put as task to queue or simply let it to be picked by cron.