# Running a admin function at a certain time

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase

I'm currently working on an Android app that needs to randomly retrieve a user and match them up with another user once a certain date, which is stored in the database, arrives. Is there anyway I can somehow incorporate an admin function that does this into the app? I've tried looking at Google's App Engine and scheduling tasks with Cron, but that seems to only work for intervals or on specific dates.

Comment: What does this have to do with Firebase, Eric? Are we talking about the new Functions launch here?

Comment: @Kato I'm making a "gift exchange" app, where users have until a certain deadline to sign up. Once this deadline arrives, i want all the users who have signed up for that gift exchange to be randomly matched up. I'm storing all my app data inside of the Firebase realtime database, including the deadlines for each exchange. However, i'm not sure how to go about matching users up, as this would have to be different for each gift exchange.

Comment: If you want to do this with Cloud Functions for Firebase, you could schedule the execution of an HTTPS Cloud Function using a third party cron scheduler such as http://cron-job.org/

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For one way to make an *app-programmable cron* check [How to schedule repeated jobs or tasks from user parameters in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715878/how-to-schedule-repeated-jobs-or-tasks-from-user-parameters-in-google-app-engine/42721205#42721205)

Typically you'd also add `login: admin` to the cron's handler, to ensure no accidental non-admin execution, which should take care of the admin portion (if I understand it correctly).