# Dynamic scheduler on GCP

Tags: api, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

Does GCP have a job scheduling service like Azure Scheduler, where jobs can be scheduled and managed dynamically via API?

Google Cron service is set in a static file and it seems like their answer to this is to use that to poke a roll your own service backed with PubSub and a data store.  Looking for Quartz-like functionality, consumable by APP engine, which can be managed and invoked via API as opposed to managing a cluster, queue, and compute instance/VM deployment of Quartz (or the like) or rolling a custom solution.  Should support 50 million simultaneous jobs per day with retry / recoverability and dynamic scheduling per tenant capabilities.

This is the cheapest and easiest way I can imagine building a solution today on top of an existing AppEngine based project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, currently there is no such API/service directly available on GCP. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3638) (on GAE) for it.

But, also as you observed, it is possible to build and use a custom solution, just like the one you proposed.

Depending on the context even simpler solutions are possible. For a GAE context check out, for example, [How to schedule repeated jobs or tasks from user parameters in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715878/how-to-schedule-repeated-jobs-or-tasks-from-user-parameters-in-google-app-engine/42721205#42721205).