# Creating a one off cron job using firebase and app engine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, cron-task

I'm creating an app where a user can create a piece of data that could be presented in the ui at a later date. I'm trying to find a way to create cron entries dynamically using either java code (for android devices) or node.js code (firebase cloud function generates a cron job). I haven't been able to find a way to do it dynamically and based on what I read it may not be possible. Does anyone out there know a way?

Comment: Don't create dynamic cron entries. Create one cron, that runs every minute (or day, or hour, or whatever) that checks a database for these dynamic tasks, and executes the ones that are currently due.

Answer (score 0):

Presently the only way to create GAE cron jobs is via deployment of a cron configuration file (by itself or, in *some* cases, together with the app code). Which today can only be done via CLI tools (from the GAE or Cloud SDKs).

I'm unsure if you'd consider programmatically invoking such CLI tools qualifying to 'create cron entries dynamically'. If you do - generation the cron config file and scripting the desired CLI-based deployment would be an approach.

But creating jobs via an API is still a feature request, see [How to schedule repeated jobs or tasks from user parameters in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715878/how-to-schedule-repeated-jobs-or-tasks-from-user-parameters-in-google-app-engine/42721205#42721205). It also contains another potentially acceptable approach (along the same lines as the one mentioned in @ceejayoz's comment))