# Google App Engine - How to set up Cron job using seconds

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

When setting up a Google App Engine instance you can configure a [cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref) to set up Cron jobs.

There does not seem to be any documentation on how to configure jobs that run say every 30 seconds.

I tried

```
schedule: every 30 seconds
```

and

```
schedule: 0/30 0 0 ? * * *
```

But no good. Google Cloud tells me the format is incorrect when I deploy. Can you schedule in frequencies less then 1 minute with Google App Engine Cron jobs?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot configure GAE cron services with resolutions below 1 minute. FWIW, you can't do that on unix/linux systems either.

But it is possible to use an `every 1 minutes` cron job from which you can further trigger delayed execution of deferred/push/pull queue tasks with down to 1 second resolution, see [High frequency data refresh with Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206365/high-frequency-data-refresh-with-google-app-engine/35206885#35206885)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, solved with `setTimeout()`.
Using setTimeout for 30 seconds inside the appengine one-minute cron job did the trick, in this case we'll be fetching data 2 times per minute that is every 30 seconds.

`saveData();
setTimeout(function () { saveData(); }, 30000);`

Tested and worked fine,

Comment: This would mean the function would be running for a significant fraction of every minute. Let's say 60%of the time. At $0.0025/thousand GB-seconds, and $0.01/thousand CPU-seconds, I calculate a 30 day cost of $16.54 for this solution for a typical 256MiB function. Still, it's a solution.

Comment: Also, this solution may require some kind of async await or promise mechanism to prevent the server from being killed after it runs off the end of the function body.

Comment: This is going to end badly when the app engine starts to scale and you have multiple instances.