# Scheduling cron job to trigger cloud function

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to schedule a cron job using the cron.yaml to trigger a HTTP cloud function. I tried to implement it but passing the entire URL is throwing an error.

```
cron:
- description: "Test Call"
  url: https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/helloGET
  schedule: every 1 mins
```

I see this error in the console when I try to deploy the cron job

```
Unable to assign value 'https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/helloGET' to attribute 'url':
Value 'https://us-central1-***.cloudfunctions.net/helloGET' for url does not match expression '^(?:^/.*$)$'
  in "/Users/xyz/Desktop/cron.yaml", line 3, column 8
```

I know that error is being thrown because I have the full URL path but instead of the full path if I just pass the following

```
cron:
- description: "Test Call"
  url: /helloGET
  schedule: every 1 mins
```

then it is able to deploy the cron job but when the job is run it throws a 404 error because by just passing the path and not the full URL I believe it is looking for the URL in the app engine and since I dont have any code in the app engine and my service call is in the cloud function it is not able to find it.

Also is there a way to set the schedule to be run every 1 seconds instead of 1 mins.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain fully what's going wrong, including any error messages.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added additional information

Comment: If you're getting an error in the console when you're trying to deploy, that probably means there's a problem with your code.  Without seeing the code, it's not possible to diagnose here.

Comment: Looking for a solution too. My case is I want to schedule trigger background GCF with last payload. Something like retry my background GCF with same payload

Answer (score 1):

The url in the `cron.yaml` needs to be a URl handled by your app, not an arbitrary one - which is why only the relative path works. From [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#syntax) (emphasis mine):

> **url**
>
> Required. The url field specifies a URL **in your application** that
>   will be invoked by the Cron Service.

What you can do is have your application cron handler reach out to the arbitrary URL you need to trigger your Cloud Function. See [Issuing HTTP(S) Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests)

As for going below 1 minute intervals - that's not supported by cron itself. But there are ways to achieve something almost equivalent, see, for example [High frequency data refresh with Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206365/high-frequency-data-refresh-with-google-app-engine/35206885#35206885)